# crossdoman.xml flash sand box violation

Tags: flash, sandbox, crossdomain.xml

I have a crossdomain.xml file sitting in my WebServer folder on a web:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Just to try and get it to work, I actually put it in every folder in the path to my web page as well but with the same result when I try to run the test movie from flash professional:

```
*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to loadNews(http://devbox.net/Media/links/ticker.xml) halted - not permitted from file:////Volumes/Mac%20Pro%20HD/Users/norm/Desktop/ticker/rssTest.swf
problem loading the XML
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

*Cross domain policies* can be tricky (and nightmarish at times).

Your *policy XML* looks just fine, but is it on the **same domain** as your XML file? There will need to be that (or similar) policy at http://devbox.net/crossdomain.xml or else you **won't be able to load ticker.xml**.